# linux driver on PowerPC

Tags: driver, cross-compiling, powerpc

I am trying to compile a very simple driver for powerpc using the cross-compile tool : powerpc-linux-gnu.

here is the code, `driver.c`:

```
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
static int __init test_driver_init(void) {
    printk("hello world.");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit test_driver_exit(void){
    /* deregister this driver*/
    printk("goodbye.");
}
module_init(test_driver_init);
module_exit(test_driver_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

and the `Makefile`

```
obj-m := driver.o
KDIR = /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/
all:
    $(MAKE) ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=powerpc-linux-gnu- -Wall -C $(KDIR) M=$(PWD)
clean:
    rm -f *.order *.symvers *.mod.c *.mod.o *.ko *.o *.tmp_versionample driver module
```

when I do `make`, it occurs some errors:

```
make ARCH=powerpc CROSS_COMPILE=powerpc-linux-gnu- -Wall -C /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/ M=/home/sqzhang/tdriver
make[1]: 正在进入目录 `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69'
  CC [M]  /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.o
In file included from /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/arch/powerpc/include/asm/bitops.h:267:0,
                 from include/linux/bitops.h:17,
                 from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/arch/powerpc/include/asm/system.h:7,
                 from include/linux/list.h:7,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
include/asm-generic/bitops/find.h:12:50: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 #define find_first_bit(addr, size) find_next_bit((addr), (size), 0)
                                                  ^
include/linux/bitops.h:164:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘find_first_bit’
 extern unsigned long find_first_bit(const unsigned long *addr,
                      ^
include/asm-generic/bitops/find.h:12:58: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 #define find_first_bit(addr, size) find_next_bit((addr), (size), 0)
                                                          ^
include/linux/bitops.h:164:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘find_first_bit’
 extern unsigned long find_first_bit(const unsigned long *addr,
                      ^
include/asm-generic/bitops/find.h:12:66: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 #define find_first_bit(addr, size) find_next_bit((addr), (size), 0)
                                                                  ^
include/linux/bitops.h:164:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘find_first_bit’
 extern unsigned long find_first_bit(const unsigned long *addr,
                      ^
include/asm-generic/bitops/find.h:13:60: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 #define find_first_zero_bit(addr, size) find_next_zero_bit((addr), (size), 0)
                                                            ^
include/linux/bitops.h:174:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘find_first_zero_bit’
 extern unsigned long find_first_zero_bit(const unsigned long *addr,
                      ^
include/asm-generic/bitops/find.h:13:68: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before ‘(’ token
 #define find_first_zero_bit(addr, size) find_next_zero_bit((addr), (size), 0)
                                                                    ^
include/linux/bitops.h:174:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘find_first_zero_bit’
 extern unsigned long find_first_zero_bit(const unsigned long *addr,
                      ^
include/asm-generic/bitops/find.h:13:76: error: expected declaration specifiers or ‘...’ before numeric constant
 #define find_first_zero_bit(addr, size) find_next_zero_bit((addr), (size), 0)
                                                                            ^
include/linux/bitops.h:174:22: note: in expansion of macro ‘find_first_zero_bit’
 extern unsigned long find_first_zero_bit(const unsigned long *addr,
                      ^
In file included from include/linux/kernel.h:16:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/arch/powerpc/include/asm/system.h:7,
                 from include/linux/list.h:7,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
include/linux/log2.h:32:5: error: redefinition of ‘__ilog2_u32’
 int __ilog2_u32(u32 n)
     ^
In file included from include/linux/bitops.h:17:0,
                 from include/linux/kernel.h:15,
                 from /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/arch/powerpc/include/asm/system.h:7,
                 from include/linux/list.h:7,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/arch/powerpc/include/asm/bitops.h:179:5: note: previous definition of ‘__ilog2_u32’ was here
 int __ilog2_u32(u32 n)
     ^
In file included from include/linux/module.h:9:0,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
include/linux/list.h: In function ‘list_del’:
include/linux/list.h:106:2: error: implicit declaration of function ‘_AC’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
  entry->next = LIST_POISON1;
  ^
In file included from include/linux/list.h:5:0,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
include/linux/poison.h:12:65: error: ‘UL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 # define POISON_POINTER_DELTA _AC(CONFIG_ILLEGAL_POINTER_VALUE, UL)
                                                                 ^
include/linux/poison.h:22:46: note: in expansion of macro ‘POISON_POINTER_DELTA’
 #define LIST_POISON1  ((void *) 0x00100100 + POISON_POINTER_DELTA)
                                              ^
include/linux/list.h:106:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘LIST_POISON1’
  entry->next = LIST_POISON1;
                ^
include/linux/poison.h:12:65: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
 # define POISON_POINTER_DELTA _AC(CONFIG_ILLEGAL_POINTER_VALUE, UL)
                                                                 ^
include/linux/poison.h:22:46: note: in expansion of macro ‘POISON_POINTER_DELTA’
 #define LIST_POISON1  ((void *) 0x00100100 + POISON_POINTER_DELTA)
                                              ^
include/linux/list.h:106:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘LIST_POISON1’
  entry->next = LIST_POISON1;
                ^
include/linux/list.h: In function ‘hlist_del’:
include/linux/poison.h:12:65: error: ‘UL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 # define POISON_POINTER_DELTA _AC(CONFIG_ILLEGAL_POINTER_VALUE, UL)
                                                                 ^
include/linux/poison.h:22:46: note: in expansion of macro ‘POISON_POINTER_DELTA’
 #define LIST_POISON1  ((void *) 0x00100100 + POISON_POINTER_DELTA)
                                              ^
include/linux/list.h:579:12: note: in expansion of macro ‘LIST_POISON1’
  n->next = LIST_POISON1;
            ^
In file included from /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/arch/powerpc/include/asm/atomic.h:474:0,
                 from include/linux/spinlock.h:321,
                 from include/linux/seqlock.h:29,
                 from include/linux/time.h:8,
                 from include/linux/stat.h:60,
                 from include/linux/module.h:10,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
include/asm-generic/atomic64.h: At top level:
include/asm-generic/atomic64.h:17:3: error: conflicting types for ‘atomic64_t’
 } atomic64_t;
   ^
In file included from include/linux/prefetch.h:13:0,
                 from include/linux/list.h:6,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
include/linux/types.h:197:3: note: previous declaration of ‘atomic64_t’ was here
 } atomic64_t;
   ^
In file included from include/linux/sched.h:63:0,
                 from /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69/arch/powerpc/include/asm/elf.h:5,
                 from include/linux/elf.h:7,
                 from include/linux/module.h:14,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
include/linux/mm_types.h:248:2: error: unknown type name ‘mm_context_t’
  mm_context_t context;
  ^
In file included from include/linux/list.h:5:0,
                 from include/linux/module.h:9,
                 from /home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.c:2:
include/linux/rculist.h: In function ‘list_del_rcu’:
include/linux/poison.h:12:65: error: ‘UL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 # define POISON_POINTER_DELTA _AC(CONFIG_ILLEGAL_POINTER_VALUE, UL)
                                                                 ^
include/linux/poison.h:23:46: note: in expansion of macro ‘POISON_POINTER_DELTA’
 #define LIST_POISON2  ((void *) 0x00200200 + POISON_POINTER_DELTA)
                                              ^
include/linux/rculist.h:97:16: note: in expansion of macro ‘LIST_POISON2’
  entry->prev = LIST_POISON2;
                ^
include/linux/rculist.h: In function ‘list_replace_rcu’:
include/linux/poison.h:12:65: error: ‘UL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 # define POISON_POINTER_DELTA _AC(CONFIG_ILLEGAL_POINTER_VALUE, UL)
                                                                 ^
include/linux/poison.h:23:46: note: in expansion of macro ‘POISON_POINTER_DELTA’
 #define LIST_POISON2  ((void *) 0x00200200 + POISON_POINTER_DELTA)
                                              ^
include/linux/rculist.h:143:14: note: in expansion of macro ‘LIST_POISON2’
  old->prev = LIST_POISON2;
              ^
include/linux/rculist.h: In function ‘hlist_del_rcu’:
include/linux/poison.h:12:65: error: ‘UL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 # define POISON_POINTER_DELTA _AC(CONFIG_ILLEGAL_POINTER_VALUE, UL)
                                                                 ^
include/linux/poison.h:23:46: note: in expansion of macro ‘POISON_POINTER_DELTA’
 #define LIST_POISON2  ((void *) 0x00200200 + POISON_POINTER_DELTA)
                                              ^
include/linux/rculist.h:286:13: note: in expansion of macro ‘LIST_POISON2’
  n->pprev = LIST_POISON2;
             ^
include/linux/rculist.h: In function ‘hlist_replace_rcu’:
include/linux/poison.h:12:65: error: ‘UL’ undeclared (first use in this function)
 # define POISON_POINTER_DELTA _AC(CONFIG_ILLEGAL_POINTER_VALUE, UL)
                                                                 ^
include/linux/poison.h:23:46: note: in expansion of macro ‘POISON_POINTER_DELTA’
 #define LIST_POISON2  ((void *) 0x00200200 + POISON_POINTER_DELTA)
                                              ^
include/linux/rculist.h:306:15: note: in expansion of macro ‘LIST_POISON2’
  old->pprev = LIST_POISON2;
               ^
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [/home/sqzhang/tdriver/driver.o] 错误 1
make[1]: *** [_module_/home/sqzhang/tdriver] 错误 2
make[1]:正在离开目录 `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69'
make: *** [all] 错误 2
```

Could anybody help me ? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Good news: your driver code looks fine for a recent kernel.

The bad news: you likely have a problem in your toolchain and/or base kernel tree setup.

It looks like the kernel headers you're compiling against are conflicting with another set of headers (`/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69` vs. `include/`). Check that `/usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69` doesn't assume a non-powerpc architecture. Does it use a powerpc `.config`?

Also, the kernel source tree you're building against (2.6.32) is super old - we're currently at 4.3. Is there any reason you need to use this version? If not, I'd suggest updating.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have checked the kernel of my system. It's the same, so It may be not because of the kernel headers conflicts. And I don't know how to "Check that /usr/src/linux-2.6.32.69 doesn't assume a non-powerpc architecture". Could you tell tell me more? ps:I have to use this version, that's a long story. Thank you for your advice :D